# Finding the closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+n} \frac{\log(k+n)}{k n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

A while ago I computed pretty easily the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+n} \frac{\log(k+n)}{k+ n}$  and then I thought of tackling the case where we have the product instead of sum in denominator, but this one  seems far harder than the previous one. What would you suggest me to do?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+n} \frac{\log(k+n)}{k n}$$

Comment: *What would you suggest me to do?* - I'd suggest you tell us how you evaluated the first series in the first place.

Comment: @Lucian I started with the simple fact that $$\int_0^{\infty} \log(x) e^{-s x} \ dx =-\frac{1}{s}(\log(s)+\gamma)$$ The rest of the work should flow naturally (there are some things to write down, I cannot share in a comment the whole proof). Doing like that with the desired double sum I reached some unapproachable results that I don't wanna recollect now.

Comment: The $\dfrac{\ln(k+n)}{k+n}$ comes from some $\dfrac1{(k+n)^a}~.~$ But $\dfrac{\ln(k+n)}{kn}$ comes from $\ldots$ ? It doesn't seem at all reasonable to expect a closed form for the second series merely because the former has one.

Comment: @Lucian I see your point, and partially I agree, but studying similar forms of some series that have closed forms might be interesting, at least to me. I wouldn't like to only study things I believe they have a closed form since I might be wrong in many cases. Besides that, finding integrals and series without closed forms seems to be by far a great challenge.

Comment: Replacing $\ln(k+n)$ with $\ln(kn)=\ln k+\ln n$ will probably yield a closed form as well.

Comment: @Lucian The series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+n} \frac{\log(k+n)}{k+ n}$ is one of the most beautiful series I ever computed. I liked it so much that I also dedicated some study to other similar forms of it.

Comment: @Lucian And it's particularly nice when trying to compute it by series manipulation only.

Answer (score 1):

By [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html),
$$\log(k+n)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-(k+n)x}}{x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
and since $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}=-\log(1-z)$ we have:
$$ \sum_{k,n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+n}}{kn}=\log^2 2\tag{2}$$
and the whole sum equals:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-x}\log^2 2 -\log^2(1+e^{-x})\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(1+t)-t \log^2 2}{t \log t}\,dt\tag{3}$$
that is not so horrible.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for trying that. I worked on that for a while but I didn't get anything satisfactory.